# Google Compute VM's as DNS servers not working

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine

I have little experience with DNS servers, the experience i do have is limited to creating zones and managing subdomains and stuff like that - pretty basic. I've been experiencing some problems to setup a master and slave dns server do host my domains within Google Cloud. I have setup the both servers and tested it from inside google cloud network, when i try to use it externally - like registering a new domain and point its zone there it doesn't work.. I can't reach the server. When i try a "dig -x IPADDR" from outside i get a Google Cloud like reverse DNS, i can't reach my server. I have already added the port 53 tcp and udp on the firewall, but still nothing. Could someone give me some adivice on how to proceed so i can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are trying to setup DNS servers in Compute Engine? I think the better way to provide DNS in Google Cloud is to us their DNS service:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/